# How to use ArcPy to list feature class and number of rows per feature class?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I would like to iterate a geodatabse to get the name of each feature class/data set in it, in addition to the number of rows in the feature class. I would also like to identify whether the dataset that is being printed is a feature class or feature dataset.

The code that I have now prints each feature class and feature data set; but does not denote whether if the object printed is a feature class or feature data set.  How would I print the number of rows per feature class in addition to denote whether if it is a feature class or feature dataset?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 and a direct connect via spatial database.

```
import arcpy   
arcpy.env.workspace='myworkspace'

    datasetList = arcpy.ListDatasets("*", "Feature")
    for dataset in datasetList:
        print dataset
        fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","",dataset)
        fcList.sort()
        for fc in fcList:
            print fc
        for fc in fcList:
            arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)
```

Sample Output:

```
SDEDEV.SDE.Boundaries
SDEDEV.SDE.CTYA_GLEN
SDEDEV.SDE.ZipCode
SDEDEV.SDE.Streets
SDEDEV.SDE.CAMS_Streets_2012
SDEDEV.SDE.ROW
SDEDEV.SDE.Streets_COG
```

Comment: It's a violation of best practice (and dangerous to geodatabase integrity) to load any spatial data as the SDE user.  The SDE user should be reserved for enterprise geodatabase administration; one or more data ownership accounts should instead be created, with roles to manage access to still more user logins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [docs for GetCount](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000n7000000) don't say it very well but it returns a gp result object and not a number.. to get a number (see example 2) you need to use `getOutput(0)` and `int`.

Your script (modified):

```
import arcpy   
arcpy.env.workspace='myworkspace'

    datasetList = arcpy.ListDatasets("*", "Feature")
    for dataset in datasetList:
        print dataset
        fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","",dataset)
        fcList.sort()
        for fc in fcList:
            cnt = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fc).getOutput(0))
            print "{0} {1}".format(fc,cnt) # print in the format "fcname count"
```

Comment: off-topic - is there a good reason why they've written it this way, or is it a bug/mistake?

Comment: @StephenLead I'd say it has to be to do with how it's used in model builder. Prior to v9.3 it used to just return an int; It's definitely one of the more obscure and confusing cases in arcpy (and even ArcObjects).

Comment: @StephenLead  I think there was a decision made that every geoprocessing tool would return a result object so that we did not have to remember which did and which didn't. If I can find a reference I'll pass it on.

Comment: @StephenLead its here http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/using-tools-in-python.htm

Comment: @PolyGeo that does make a lot of sense. Clearly they put a lot of thought into it (and are much smarter than me!)